# One access token for OAuth using Twitter API

Tags: python, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to use a one access token with OAuth to make calls to the Twitter API. I am NOT trying to build a web application but rather trying to harvest data from Twitter to perform some analysis. I would like to collect three types of data : followers, friends and user information including status updates. I am able to do all the same using no authentication as the data I collect are from **public** users only. However, due to [API limits](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting#rest) I would like to shift to Oauth which would allow me to get access to 350 requests per hour.

Is OAuth one access token the right approach for my task?

Is there any documentation or example to do the same? I am not using any wrapper. Wrappers like [Python-Twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) and [Twython](https://github.com/kumar303/twython) don't allow functions to access followers, status updates of other users i.e. users with data publicly available. I use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to directly call the URL as given on the [Twitter API documentation website](http://dev.twitter.com/doc).

I have registered an application and have all the keys (API key, Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, Access Secret Key) with me. I would just like to get myself authenticated and mine Twitter to collect data.

Programming Language : Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [Python-Oauth2](https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2) library to achieve a one access token.

Answer (score 0):

You will get 350 requests per hour and access token. An access token basically represents the relationship between your application and a user.

So, as far as I know, for every user you are able to get to authorize your application - you will get 350 more requests.

Comment: Jon, I think I clearly mentioned that I am NOT trying to build an application. In any case, I was able to use the python-oauth2 library  for performing one token access.